# Can an angel perform multiple agencies?

Tags: midrash, malach-angel

Bereishis Rabbah 50:2 states that one angel cannot perform multiple tasks:

> אין מלאך אחד עושה שתי שליחות ולא שתי מלאכים עושים שליחות אחד.
>
> One angel cannot perform two agencies, nor can two angels perform a single agency.

Yet Eichah Rabbah 2:3 states that Gavriel performed *three* agencies:

> אמר רבי יוחנן למלאך קשה שביניהם אמר זה גבריאל שנאמר ואיש אחד בתוכם לבש בדים וקסת בספר במתניו. ג׳ דברים היה אותו מלאך משמש קסנטור ספקלטור וכהן גדול.
>
> R’ Yochanan said: [G-d spoke] to the angel who was the most severe of them - This was Gavriel, as it says, “but one man among them was clothed in linen, with a scribe’s slate at his loins.” This angel served three functions: scribe, executioner, and High Priest.

How can these sources be reconciled? Can an angel have only one mission, or can he have three? If you want to argue that, for whatever reason, Gavriel is different, the Midrash in Bereishis Rabbah proceeds to detail which angels were involved and which task each one had:

> מיכאל אמר בשורתו ונסתלק גבריאל נשתלח להפך את סדום ורפאל להציל את לוט.
>
> Michael said his news [that Avraham would have a son] and left; **Gavriel was sent to destroy Sedom;** and Refael to save Lot.

But if Gavriel can perform multiple agencies, let him do all three! Are we forced to say that these Midrashim are in conflict, or is there a way of reconciling them?

(I see that the Anaf Yosef to Eichah Rabbah asks this question, leaving it unanswered. He’s referenced in note 69 in the Artscroll edition, and the piece in question is written out on the Hebrew side on page ד, for those who want to see him inside.)

Comment: There isn't a controdiction if you understand that the multiple agencies are not taking place simultaneously and that gavriel did each of these things one at a time. Another plausible explanation is the first source is a general rule for angels but gavriel is unique amongst angels in that it is an angel that is able to do multiple taskes simultaneously

Comment: @Dude To respond to the first claim I present to you the angel Refael, which the Midrash in Bereishis Rabbah previously established healed Avraham as well, yet everyone asks the same question of one angel doing multiple agencies. If you’d like I can try to locate the precise sources and edit them in. To respond to the second claim, please reread beginning with the paragraph sandwiched between the two quotes beginning with “If you want to argue that, for whatever reason, Gavriel is different.”

Comment: what about the malach YHVH? Is this one and the same, if so it seems to be fulfilling multiple tasks

Comment: @Levi I must be misunderstanding what you’re referring to, as Hashem is not a Malach.

Comment: @DonielF No no, I didn’t mean that at all! What I meant was that in the Tenach we don’t find the names of the malachim being sent, but sometimes we find terms like malach ha’elohim, or malach YHVH, this happens more than once. So my question was wether or not one and the same messenger is descibed as such, or if it are more than one and the same which is refered to as such. If it’s one and the same malach in each of the cases it seems that this angel fulfilled multiple tasks during certain situations.

Comment: @Levi It’s my understanding that some malachim perform one task and then are destroyed in the river of fire (probably a mashal), while others survive to perform a different task at a later time. I’d assume that the ones given permanent names are the ones which last, while the ones which don’t last are given temporary names (compare למה תשאל את שמי והוא פלאי), and are thus simply called מלאך ה׳ or the like. I could be way off, but that’s always been my understanding.

Comment: Malach & Gavriel is different. I've seen in many seforim the idea that malach is a simple Malach, while Gavriel is Gavriel

Comment: @FalseMessiah I’d be curious where you saw that, because the Gemara explicitly says that one of the “malachim” (Bereishis 19:1) was Gavriel (BM 86b). There are different types of malachim, yes, but they’re all still malachim.

Comment: It was a commentary in the back of the mesivta or in the back of a Rambam ohz vahadar in sefer mada. I don't remember. But remember, nothing ever is not reconciled

Comment: @False Well the easiest reconciliation is saying that you're remembering improperly, that perhaps what they said is that Gavriel is unique among Malachim, but he's still a Malach. But if you are remembering correctly that's grounds to start a new question of how whichever commentary said that can contradict an explicit Gemara.

Comment: No no, Gavriel is a malach, it's just that Gavriel has the ability to do more then 3 things at one time, just like the satan, yetzer hara & malach hamaves are all one...doing the same thing at once... malach hamaves.... satan (malach - see Shabbos 88 89) yetzer hara (likutei moharan tanina torah alef).... Malachim aren't names unless they are one of the 10 species, otherwise they're created to do a mission and go bye bye..

Comment: Gavriel is here to stay no matter how many things he's gotta be doing

Comment: @False My understanding of the various sources is that most Malachim are created, sing Shirah, and immediately are dissolved in the River of Fire (however literally you want to take that Midrash), while the named Malachim come down to this world, perform their sole mission for that trip, then return back Above to receive their next mission. So Gavriel can do lots of things, but not in the same trip. Similar idea for the Satan/Malach HaMaves (which indeed is how the [Maharsha to that Gemara, BB 16a](https://sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.8?p2=Chidushei_Agadot_on_Bava_Batra.16a.4), understands it).

Comment: I guess malachim don't have WhatsApp lol